# How do I flatten a YAML file so it has no aliases (in ruby)?

Tags: ruby, yaml

Let's say I have:

```
-: &defaults
  client_id: 'invalid_client_id'
  client_secret: 'secret'

production:
  <<: *defaults
staging:
  <<: *defaults
```

and I want to read it and then flatten it so there are no aliases. How would I do that? I would super prefer a solution that utilizes some configuration of the current YAML library rather than something tossed together (if that makes sense).

IOW:

```
production:
  client_id: 'invalid_client_id'
  client_secret: 'secret'
staging:
  client_id: 'invalid_client_id'
  client_secret: 'secret'
```

Edit:

The suggestion to do YAML.dump from a YAML.load works but it leaves the original alias in the document:

```
---
"-":
  client_id: invalid_client_id
  client_secret: secret
production:
  client_id: invalid_client_id
  client_secret: secret
staging:
  client_id: invalid_client_id
  client_secret: secret
```

Which is not exactly what I need. Happy to accept the answer but want to see if there are any other ideas.

Comment: It does not leave the alias it leaves the node. The alias is `&defaults`. These are separate concerns in the parser

Comment: What if the alias was nested at another level how would you want that stripped out?

Comment: I just realized that yes, there's a node and an alias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want in your amended question breaks YAML itself. In this case you should remove your initial alias manually:

```
require 'yaml'
yml = YAML.load(File.open 't.yml')
yml.delete('-')
yml.to_yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `YAML.dump`

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML::load(File.open('t.yml'))
YAML.dump yaml
```

Comment: Is there any way to tell YAML (or psych) that I just want it flattened? This is a good answer I'm just hoping there is a less round-about way.

Comment: despite my best efforts, this looks like the only solution.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work: It leaves the aliases in the document. Is there any other way?